# Why doesn't Regexp match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody please tell me why doesn't this Regexp match?

```
var matches = ' @test'.match(new RegExp('(\s+|^)(@|!)(.*?)(\s+|$)', 'g'));
```

whereas this one matches:

```
var matches = '@test'.match(new RegExp('(\s+|^)(@|!)(.*?)(\s+|$)', 'g'));
```

I have already specified `\s+`. Why wouldn't it match it then?

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but why structure your regex like that... wont this be better? ^(\s*)(@|!)(.*?)(\s+|$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` is not recognized as the whitespace shorthand because you're constructing the regex from a string instead of a regex literal, and inside a string you need to double the backslashes.

So you need to use

```
var matches = ' @test'.match(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)([@!])(.*?)(\\s+|$)', 'g'));
```

or

```
var matches = ' @test'.match(/(\s+|^)([@!])(.*?)(\s+|$)/g);
```

Comment: :) didn't catch that one. Correct

Comment: @Mutahhir - This also works: `' @test'.match(/(\s+|^)(@|!)(.*?)(\s+|$)/g);`

Comment: yup, sure does. I prefer this, which is why I didn't catch the escape character problem.